# Webserver configuration to get Drupal Clean Urls work proper

Tags: webserver, drupal

I have just configured a local web-server and migrated a site built on Drupal 7 onto it.

Front page is loaded just fine but when i try to navigate i get 404 error. I`ve noticed that using not clean urls fixes it: mysite.com/?q=neaded-page

So what kind of package or module or changes do i need to install/make to get it work proper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable mod_rewrite. 
Try with:

http://drupal.org/node/134439

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn`t fixed the problem.

Comment: Edited with the link to a more comprehensive tutorial.